# Visual Studio - How to add elements to left panel?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Basically I want to add Toolbox and SQL Server Object Explorer to my VS to be added to my left panel.

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

I want this (disregard the colors of course):

[image]

I cannot figure out how to do it - been messing with this for a good 30 minutes now.

Answer (score 3):

Try reading this link: [How to Arrange and Dock Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4y0hsax.aspx) ...

> **To dock tool windows and document windows:**
>
> Click the tool window or document window you want to dock.
>
> Drag the window toward the middle of the IDE.
>
> A guide diamond appears. The four arrows of the diamond point toward
>   the four sides of the editing pane. If the window is a tool window, an
>   additional four arrows point to the four edges of the IDE.
>
> When the window you are dragging reaches the location where you want
>   to dock it, move the pointer over the corresponding portion of the
>   guide diamond. The designated area is shaded.
>
> To dock the window in the position indicated, release the mouse
>   button.
>
> For example, if Solution Explorer is docked on the right edge of the
>   IDE and you want to dock it on the left edge, drag Solution Explorer
>   toward the middle of the IDE, move the pointer over the far left arrow
>   of the guide diamond, and then release the mouse button.
>
> Alternatively, you can dock a tool window to a portion of one of the
>   side walls of the IDE by dragging it to the side until you see a
>   secondary guide diamond. Click one of the four arrows to dock the tool
>   window to that portion of the side wall.

Comment: Thanks. In VS2017, the traditional right dock of the Solution Explorer interferes with module preview on the right, thus it might be a better idea to dock the Solution Explorer to the left panel as well.